# Associate MembershipUser with Another Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I am working on a project where I am using the membershipuser for authentication, but based on the role of the user I am going to need additional information (different for each role).  I know I can extend the membership user in different ways, but I am also wondering if I should just create another class for these additional fields and just use the guid of the membershipuser to find this information.  Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Wade

Answer (score 0):

Based on tag in OP, you are using legacy ASP.Net Membership Provider or [ASP.Net Universal Provider](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

If so, the easiest way will be to create separate table. Then add foreign key to your tables.

[image]

***Note:*** If you add columns to Membership tables, you will need to create Custom Membership Provider. In other words, Default Membership Provider will not work if you add columns to their tables.

If you are developing new application, you might want to look at [ASP.Net Identity 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx) which allows to add custom columns to their tables.